# ASP.Net MVC - Swashbuckle Not Recognizing Any Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to integrate Swagger UI into my ASP.Net MVC project using Swashbuckle and I am having problems with Swashbuckle not recognizing any of my controllers/endpoints.

For simplicity I created a brand new project with a single controller that is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestAPI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Home")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("Home/About")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        } 

        [Route("Home/Contact")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
   }
}
```

I used Nuget to add Swashbuckle using the following command:

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle
```

I kept all of the default configuration for both the overall project as well as for Swashbuckle itself (Using the generated file SwaggerConfig.cs)

When I navigate to the Swagger endpoint I am greeted by an empty Swagger definition and none of my controllers/endpoints are showing up.

[Empty Swagger Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbQ2D.png)

I am at a loss for how to get my Controllers/Endpoints to show up. All of the Swashbuckle demo's make it seem like this base configuration will at the very least make the endpoints display.

Thanks!

EDIT: The following is my SwaggerConfig.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using TestAPI;
using Swashbuckle.Application;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace TestAPI
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "TestAPI");
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Swagger-integration-in-da408b29

Comment: @NevilleNazerane These were the steps I followed to get things up and running. For some reason it seems like the routes are not being recognized by Swashbuckle or something along those lines.

Comment: @CharlesBisbee what version of .NET MVC are you using?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck I am using .NET MVC 5

Comment: Do you have a `Startup.cs` file in your project? If you do, could you include the content inside `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder application)` method?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck My project does not have a Startup.cs file

Comment: Did you try turning it off then turning it back on again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is that Swashbuckle does not work with ASP.Net MVC. It is unfortunate but Swashbuckle is not the appropriate solution for this problem. I ended up creating a custom solution using a combination of Reflection and XML comments.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the [Route]-attribute did the trick.

EG:

```
// POST: Jokes/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
// For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
[Route("[Controller]/[Action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Question,Answer")] Joke joke)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(joke);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(joke);
}
```